# How can open google map in iOS using Meteor

Tags: cordova, meteor

I need to open google/apple map app on iOS using Meteor js. I could do it in Andriod using `window.open("geo:" + addressLongLat, "_system");`, but the same code not working iOS.

Comment: I think this is an issue with loading the library within Meteor.startup. Is that how you're loading the library? If so, try place GoogleMaps.load within a template onRendered instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On iOS geo: url scheme doesn't open Google maps, it can open [Google Earth](http://www.gotschemes.com/search/?app_id=1656)

Google maps app allows this three url schemes, `comgooglemaps://`, `comgooglemaps-x-callback://` and `comgooglemapsurl://`

[More information about google maps url schemes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme)

You can also use the http url, that will open the app if it's installed or a website if it isn't

[More information about http urls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)

Also, for making `window.open` work you'll have to install `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` first. Otherwise, you'll have to use `a` links.

Also for Apple map you can use

```
window.open('maps://?q=' + addressLongLat, '_system');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `window.open('maps://?q=' + addressLongLat, '_system');` for iOS.

Reference: https://gist.github.com/danharper/844382901f7a7b73b90a

Comment: that's for Apple Maps, not for Google Maps. Also, Apple recommends using the `http://maps.apple.com/` url instead of `maps:`  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Comment: @jcesarmobile But Following code not worked for my ios device ?  `window.open('http://maps.apple.com/?q=' + addressLongLat, '_system');`

Comment: @Aboopallikara to make `window.open` work you have to install `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` first

Answer (score 2):

Using a `geo` appended link will prompt the user to open the location in the maps application of their choice (assuming the user has more than one maps application on their device).

```html
<a href="geo:-32.845027,23.006867">OPEN</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Final Answer

meteor add  cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.7.1

```
var addressLongLat = latitude + ',' + longitude;

window.open('maps://?q=' + addressLongLat, '_system'); //apple map
```

or

```
window.open('comgooglemaps://?q=' + addressLongLat, '_system'); //google map
```

Comment: maps: open Apple maps, not Google maps, you were asking about Google maps, so I think you should accept my answer instead.

Comment: the problem was not installed cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.7.1 plugin. you did not point that.

Comment: Yes, I said that on my answer before I also told you on your old answer

Comment: So please edit your answer and add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.7.1, then i can make your answer is right.